# How does JavaScript know to wait for the result of an inner promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, language-design

I am trying to wrap my head around the incredibly confusing topics of Promises in Javascript.

One of the doubts that I encountered is that what happens when a `then()` callback actually returns a promise.

Look at the code below taken from [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 1

//Actually resolves before calling the next then()

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // (*)
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2), 1000);
  });

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 2

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result * 2), 1000);
  });

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 4

});
```

Anyone of the inner promises is actually fulfilled before moving on to the next then statement.

**Why is that? How does Javascript know when the returned value is a promise itself?**

Is there really a check within the JS interpreter for this? Like something like this-:

```
if(ret_value instanceof Promise) {
  wait_for_promise(ret_value);
}
```

This does not really make sense intuitively. You would think that the return value will be kept as is, ie the next `then()` in the chain *would receive a promise and not the result of the promise.*

I come from a Java background which is probably why this loose typing is irritating me.

Comment: `then` itself returns a Promise, so you could also just do `Promise.resolve(1).then(v=>v*2).then(v=>v*2)`

Comment: @Kaiido I know then returns a Promise but then if I return a Promise explicitly how does Javascript understand to wait for its execution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It knows it's a promise because that's what the RFC spec says it should do. How it works will vary depending on which engine is processing (node, chrome, firefox, etc). This is a fundamental part of asynchronous programming that is actually getting implemented in more and more languages (C# now supports `async`/`await`). It's a symptom of Javascripts single threadness

Comment: @Liam My question is simple, if the return value of a `then()` callback is the result of the next callback then if I return a Promise then I should get back the promise object in the next `then()` callback, instead I get the resolved value of that promise. **Why is that?**

Comment: javascript does not wait at all - promises are callback sugar

Comment: Weird I can't find a dupe... So the check that is made is actually only against *thenables* (any object that has a `.then` method). If the returned value has such a method, it will call it and pass the return value as the next ring of the chain. And it is just the first paragraph of [MDN's article on Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Comment: @JaromandaX Could you please elaborate on how it is all just callback sugar? Or should I make another question for that?

Comment: @Kaiido So there is no check against whether the returned object is an instanceof Promise right? If it has a then method then it executes right? That means I can make another object with a then method and actually "trick" JS to call it? Correct? Can you give me some reference as to where you are getting the info from?

Comment: I already linked to [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Comment: read the [promise resolution procedure](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-promise-resolution-procedure) - it may help you understand - or it may not

Answer (score 4):

The actual check that is performed is against *thenables*, not only against *Promises*.

If the returned value of a Promise resolver has a `.then` method, this method will be called, and the next resolver/rejecter will receive this method's value as argument:

```js
const thenable = { // simple object, not an instance of Promise per se
  then: (res, rej) => setTimeout(() => res('from thenable'), 1000)
};
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then(v => thenable)
  .then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
     return new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(1),1000))
   })
   .then(v => {
      console.log(v); //1
   });
```

Take a look at the second then in the example above: I passed in a callback to log the value. **Because a Promise was returned in the first then, JavaScript will not execute the callback in the second then until the Promise returned from the first then is resolved**.

If, instead, in the first `then` I passed back a value (below), instead of a Promise, JavaScript would execute the callback I passed into the second `then` immediately.

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
     return 1
   })
   .then(v => {
      console.log(v); //1
   });
```

> Why is that? How does Javascript know when the returned value is a promise itself?

Maybe this can illustrate an answer to your question:

```
let x = Promise.resolve();
console.log(x instanceof Promise); //true - JavaScript "knows" that x is a promise

let y = 1;
console.log(y instanceof Promise); //false
```

Comment: Yes so you say that there is a check within the interpreter correct? Are you sure about that? I mean that's pretty inconsistent language design.

Comment: Javascript isn't Java ([not even in name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Beginnings_at_Netscape)) @ng.newbie. The language design has been influenced mainly by browser implementation ([and wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_wars)) until the W3C stepped in and started enforced a standard. If you think this is inconsistent try developing anything in Js that would work on IE and Netscape, they essentially had totally different languages

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion @kaiido s answer is the one You're searching for.

Simplified, an implementation of a promise internally could do a check like this one:

```
if( typeof(retValue.then)==="function" ) {
    retValue.then( yourCallback );
}else{
    yourCallback( retValue );
}
```

Wrote this on mobile phone. Please excuse my formatting.